# Recognition of Arabic Words using image matching

Tags: opencv

I know that there are some techniques used for Recognizing words like ANN , KNN , SVM and so on.

But these needs so many data for training and i want to cover like thousand of different words So i think of image matching so that it compare the image with a database of images and find the highest factor of matching and then it's the image.

So what do you think about that from the point of view of efficency and speed ? and can you suggest me a good matching technique to follow if there is a good one ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you think that having an image for each word (not considering different sizes and fonts, declinations, etc (I don't konw arabic :D)) would be less effort than using an OCR pre-trained for the [arabic](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.ara.tar.gz&can=2&q=)? Not considering the computation effort to segment each word and compare again this dataset... It seems impractical to me...

Comment: I guess yes because having just 1 or 2 images for each word would be less than 20+ images for a Neural Network as an example.

Comment: does arabic have just 20 words?

Comment: No I mean that I had 1000 words to recognize , for each word of the 1000 i need about 20 sample for the same name to train my neural network but in case i made image matching i'll get just 1 image for the 1000 name and compare it and the highest factor of matching will be that word.

Comment: So you have 1000 classes, and you want a 1-Nearest Neighbor classifier, where the distance function is the image matching, instead of a Neural Network? Well, 1) seems a lot of work to collect 1000 images (as soon as you automate this get 1000 or 20000 seems irrelevant). 2) Before thinking of the optimal data structure / algorithm, I'll try a proof of concept on, say, 10 words, and see if the matching approach works good enough.

Comment: Great and I am waiting for your answer after trying this approach.

Comment: ehm... probably my english is not good enough... What I meant is: if I were you, I'd try... :D

Comment: Aha fine :D thanks for your comment